# Is it wrong to hyphenate a phrasal verb like "log in" or is it a matter of style?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs, dictionaries

> People log in to Facebook.

In this sentence, if I change *log in* to *log-in*, will it be grammatically incorrect? Or the adding/omission of a hyphen is just a matter of style?

The other thing is, if *log in* is listed in dictionaries as a phrasal verb and *log-in* is not listed as a phrasal verb, will citing the dictionaries be a sufficient reason to say that adding a hyphen in *log in* is grammatically incorrect?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In formal English, adding the hyphen to ***log in*** makes your sample sentence grammatically incorrect.

The hyphen has the effect of turning the phrasal verb into an adjective or a noun. For example, these sentences are valid:

> Click here to go to the log-in page.
>
> Upon successful log-in, you will be redirected to the subscription page.

This rule mostly applies to more formal usage. I would say your average native English speaker is entirely unaware of how hyphens work with phrasal verbs.

In practical usage, especially on the Internet, "log in" is often shortened to "login," and "login" is often used as a noun, adjective, or verb.

Here's a good page on hyphenation of phrasal verbs:

http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/phrasal-verbs

Comment: I sadly have to agree with the statement about native English speakers not understanding hyphens in phrasal verbs. I've been surprised several times when people I know couldn't distinguish "Log in" from "Log-in/Login" and other similar terms, when I personally feel it makes a big difference.

Comment: Funny story, I just asked my father what the difference between login and log-in is. He does the NYT crossword every day, so I figured he would be a good person to ask. He knew that to "wake up" wouldn't take a hyphen, but that a "wake-up call" would. But he couldn't explain why. I think there are probably a lot of people like that.

Comment: Related: Could it also be "log into"?

Comment: @Barmar Ask that as a separate question.

Comment: @Barmar I would say "Log Onto" is not a common phrasal verb. I have never seen "log onto" or "log-onto." I *have* seen "log-on," but that is almost an outdated variation of "log-in."

Comment: I have seen "log into" and even "log onto", but to me both look wrong. I consider them misspellings of "log in to" and "log on to", respectively.

Comment: Right, I think ***log onto*** or ***log into*** is sometimes used, and I don't think they're incorrect. But I don't consider them phrasal verbs, so I think a ***log-onto page*** or a ***log-into page*** would be incorrect.

Comment: If `log into` is not a phrasal verb, it looks like it doesn't fit with `People log into Facebook` since it could mean something like recording (a synonym of log) something into Facebook.

Comment: @user1764381: Yes, "log into Facebook" means to record your credentials as you enter the Facebook website. It's the same idea as if you entered a secure office building and had to "log into the guest book" before you entered the building. In this case, I believe "log into the book" is short for something like: "record your log entry into the book." Most large-scale websites do keep track of when, where, and how (web browser, tablet, phone) you log in. That's part of the profile they build on you so they can target advertising successfully.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, ***log in to***, ***log on to***, ***log into***, and ***log onto*** all mean you are recording your credentials as you enter a website. The actual file on the web server where your login entry is stored is called a "log file."

Comment: With `A user logs in to Facebook`, we can have `A user logged in to Facebook` and `There is a logged-in user`. With `log into`, since it is not a phrasal verb, I find `There is a logged user` or `a user is logged` awkward. How about `log in into`? Or maybe this could be posted as an entirely different topic/question.

Comment: If you ***logged into*** Facebook or ***logged in to*** Facebook, then you would say ***I am a logged-in user***.  Just forget about the ***to*** in this case. Yes, ***there is a logged user*** and ***user is logged*** and ***log in into*** are all very awkward and/or incorrect. I would say, don't worry too much about the difference between ***into*** and ***in to*** in this context. The latter is slightly better, but both are valid and common.

Answer (score 0):

[Quick answer to be cleaned up later...]

Phrase was originally, "Please log into the system." Or reaching back further "Please log on to the system". Through speech, people dropped the preposition at the end believing the context was already implicit in their situation. This yielded "Could you log in again, Joe?" And "Log in with your username."

At some point, the datum entered when attempting to login became the login - a noun. it likely coexisted with the form "log-in" as many new nouns do initially.

Presently, i see two relevant questions regarding the verb "to login": which spelling is least ambiguous and which spelling is most popular?

Comment: *preposition*, not *proposition*